# UITableView frame height animation glitch

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

If I attempt to animate the frame height of a `tableView` (ex: `height -= 200`), the cells that appear in the last 200px disappear suddenly before the smooth animation of the frame completes.

To make sure that it's nothing else I'm doing, I created a new View-Based application. In the main `viewController` I create my own `tableview` with enough **`pseudo rows`** to fill the entire screen. And on selection of a row I do a simple height animation.

most relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTable = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)] autorelease];
    myTable.delegate = self;
    myTable.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:myTable];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGRect frame = self.myTable.frame;
    frame.size.height = 200;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:.5f];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
    self.myTable.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening, or what a fix/workaround may be?

Any suggests are really appreciated.
TIA!

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure I had *exactly* the same problem, but using `[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];` solved (parts of) the glitches (my table view slid around crazily when animating a frame height change).

Comment: thanks. solved it for me. problem: animaiting outer view (frame) - and resizing an inner textview (only new height - pos shall stay the same)

Answer (score 8):

Same problem here as well. This is what I'm doing and the origin animates smoothly, but the size changes immediately... annoying.

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"HideTabbar" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 320, 366);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

UPDATE: Try adding this before the animation:

```
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

Comment: Changing the autoresizingmask to "none" definitely worked in my situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone hitting this question & answer in the future, here's how to use @ryyst's answer in UIView's block based animations introduced in iOS 4.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            // change frame etc here
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // any clean up here
    }];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question and there are already a couple suggestions for a workaround, but I thought I'd add mine.

I ended up animating the `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` properties, which provides the illusion that the table itself is being resized.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. I imagine that tableviews have a special behavior on "setFrame:", it seems that the tableview remove the cells that won't be visible with the new frame.

In case of an animation, the cells won't be visible only at the end of the animation, but it seems that tableviews don't care.

If someone have a better theory, I'd be glad to hear it !

Comment: After days of research, this seems to be the right theory. I am not sure if anything changed in the past 9 years :) Have you seen any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found your question while seeking the proper method to resize a tableView. I think your problem is in your animation you've specified `UIView` instead of `UITableView`. I was unable to duplicate your problem using either `UIView` or `UITableView`, but I'm using **SDK 3.1** and it might be a bug that has been fixed since your post. I'm not sure, but I hope this helps!

Comment: No, it's correct to use "UIView" methods for the animation calls.

Comment: I tried the same code with 3.1 as well, and still an issue for me ;/   My current workaround is to wait for the animation to complete before resizing the tableview

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but this might help someone in the future;

I solved a similar problem by embedding the `tableview` in a `UIView`, and resizing the `UIView` instead of `tableview`. I set the `tableview's` height to a large value and also "clip subviews" property on the `UIView`. I resize the `UIView` proportional to tableview's `contentSize`. Its not a good solution but it worked for my purposes.

Comment: this will cause another problem, you wont be able to see tableView's few last cells because they are inside tableView's frame but far below the containerUIView's visible frame, so tableView will bounce when you try to scroll it because it has reached the end of the cells and yet still you can't see them

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution! there is indeed a bug!! don't use **`variables`**, when **animating the height** use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`. Like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            tableView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 38, fullScreenRect.size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-38);
}];
```

not :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            tableView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 38, fullScreenRect.size.width, fullScreenRect.size.width-38);
}];
```

and it will work like magic!